# Which way to load a huge image (canvas vs img vs background-image)?

Tags: css, html, canvas, image

### What I want

Currently I have a png image of `4000x4000`. After using [tinypng.org](http://tinypng.org/) it became just a 288KB file.

Now I want the fastes way to load the image, place it in the DOM and be able to draw a lot of canvas' on it.

I tested some and the results stunned me.

### What I tested

I made 3 tests and check only the load speed.

- (423ms) `<canvas>`
- (138ms) `<img>`
- (501ms) CSS `background-image`

The `<img>` tag is the fastest.

### Question

So, is it bad-practice to use the `<img>` tag to display a huge (background) image and use some dirty CSS to be able to draw canvas on it?

Or is it better to use canvas in my case and don't worry about the longer load time?

Comment: I'm shocked. They are using the same download method, aren't they? Maybe the difference in time is due to client-side processing? How did you measure this?

Comment: Tested using [google pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) and [firebug net](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question! This is related: [When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

From that article, if people are intended to print your page you wouldn't use `<img>` - as this would appear on the print. The same would apply to `<canvas>`, making `background-image` the logical solution.

How is your background image added through CSS? Is it inline or through its own stylesheet? If it's using its own stylesheet, have you tried [compressing the CSS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/active-gzip-compression/) before testing the speed?

This is also related, I suppose: [Do Images Load Faster in HTML or CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716262/do-images-load-faster-in-html-or-css)

Answer (score 0):

I would think of looking from a semantic perspective at your situation: What do you want to display? Is it an image on top of which you want to draw something? Is it a background image of a game board?

IMHO: 500 ms in case of CSS background is not that slow, it always takes a couple of seconds to load a website. If you care about the loading speed of the image, use `<img>`, but `HTML`ing  could be a bit more difficult because you have to fiddle around with `z-index` and `position`.

I would take the CSS background.